# Authenticated requests with a rails api, backbone.js and devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise, rails-api

I have a rails api setup using devise for auth and backbone.js for the front end. I am able to get users to sign up and sign in, but I am having trouble making subsequent requests to the api. I need to append an auth token and an email address to every request after the sign in order to make further requests but I am not sure how to do that.

The flow of my app is like so

1. send get request to /sign_in to set csrf header using custom backbone.sync
2. send post request to /sign_in with credentials and get auth token back
3. send token and email with every subsequent request

Sending the token and email with every request is the issue I'm having. How can I append it to the request in backbone?

Should I just add it to the http header like I am doing with the csrf token?

Here is my set up so far.

Api Controller with filters

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
  # This is Devise's authentication
  before_filter :authenticate_api_v1_user!

  private

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    user_email = params[:email].presence
    user = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

    if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:token])
      sign_in user, store: false
    end
  end
end
```

Session Controller

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :create
  after_action :set_csrf_header, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  def new
    render nothing: true
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:email])

    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      user.ensure_authentication_token  # make sure the user has a token generated
      render :json => { :user => user }, :status => :created
    else
      return invalid_login_attempt
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # expire auth token
    user = User.where(:authentication_token => params[:authentication_token]).first
    user.reset_authentication_token!
    render :json => { :message => ["Session deleted."] },  :success => true, :status => :ok
  end

  private

  def invalid_login_attempt
    warden.custom_failure!
    render :json => { :errors => ["Invalid email or password."] },  :success => false, :status => :unauthorized
  end

  def set_csrf_header
    response.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
  end

  def form_authenticity_token
    session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
  end

end
end
end
```

Override backbone.sync in order to set csrf headers

```
require([
'backbone',
'router',
'app',
'jquery.mobile',
'google',
'models/session_model'
], function(Backbone, Router, AppView, JQMobile, google) {
    window.Droppin = window.Droppin || {};

// overide backbone.sync
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  if (!options.noCSRF) {
    var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;

    // Set X-CSRF-Token HTTP header
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
      var token = Droppin.csrfToken;  
      if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);

      // this will include session information in the requests
      xhr.withCredentials = true;

      if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }

  var complete = options.complete;
  options.complete = function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

     // If response includes CSRF token we need to remember it
     var token = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token') 
     if (token) Droppin.csrfToken = token;

     model.trigger('sync:end');
     if (complete) complete(jqXHR, textStatus);
  };

  // Serialize data, optionally using paramRoot
  if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
    options.contentType = 'application/json';
    data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
    if (model.paramRoot) {
      data = {};
      data[model.paramRoot] = model.toJSON(options);
    } else {
      data = model.toJSON();
    }
    options.data = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return Backbone._sync(method, model, options);
};


Backbone.history.start();
new AppView();
new Router();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can overwrite globally all the jquery ajax requests to include something in the header.

Comment: Thanks, I took the response I am receiving after I log in and add it to the headers with $.ajaxSend() function and it seems to be working good.